# Facebook Share Dialogue shows Code=100 "The operation couldn’t be completed."

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, share, facebook-opengraph

The error is shown while sharing an open graph story.
There is no documentation I found on developer.facebook for the same.

on calling the function -

```
-(void) openGraphTest
{
    NSDictionary* author = [self.video objectForKey:@"author"];
    NSString *description =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"By %@", [author objectForKey:@"username"]];
    id<FBGraphObject> DiscoverObject =
    [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"discovermeapp:talent"
                                            title:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ - Episode %@",[[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"title" ],
                                                   [[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"episode_number"]]
                                            image:[[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"thumbnail_url"]
                                              url:[[self.video objectForKey: @"video"] objectForKey: @"share_url"]
                                      description:description];

    id<FBOpenGraphAction> postAction = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
    [postAction setObject:DiscoverObject forKey:@"talent"];
   // [postAction setObject:@"true" forKey: @"fb:explicitly_shared"];


    [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:postAction
                                          actionType:@"me/discovermeapp:discover"
                                 previewPropertyName:@"Discover"
                                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                 if(error) {
                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                 } else {
                                                     NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                 }
                                             }];
}
```

It temporarily opens the facebook app, and the returns back to the caller app showing 100 error.

Comment: I realised that the issue is caused because of incorrect PreviewPropertyname parameter, Changing it, solved the error

Comment: could you tell me what did you change it to? im trying to figure out what it means..  documentation is poor on this one :\

Comment: I dont exactly remember, but it was changing the preview property name, There are various such fields on facebook details. You need to check that. There is an attribute called preview property also

Comment: Where do you change the PreviewPropertyname parameter Kakshil?

Comment: I know its too late, but I changed it in the Facebook panel